# Number of subgroups within a specific subgroup

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

We are told that G is a cyclic group of order 136. How many elements are in the subgroup $\langle g^{30}\rangle$ ? How many subgroups contain this subgroup?

I used the extended euclidean algorithm and found that the gcd(136,30)=2. Then plugged that into the equation $ord(g^k)$ = n/gcd(136,30) and got 136/2= 68. I believe this means there are 68 elements in the subgroup $<g^(30)>$, is that correct?
However, I am not sure what the second question is asking. Any help would be appreciated.

I've just had a thought...since gcd=2, would it have something to do with $g^2$...as in would it be the number of groups that are multiples of 2 up to 136 (2,4,6,...,134)

Comment: You seem to be overthinking the problem.  Once you realize how big the subgroup $\langle g^{30} \rangle$ is, you should realize that the possibilities of a bigger subgroup (one that contains this) are quite limited.

Answer (score 1):

Rounding up your calculation ( and assuming you actually meant $\;G=\langle g\rangle\;$ ), observe that $\;\langle g\rangle=\langle g^{15}\rangle\;$ , since $\;gc d(136,15)=1\;$ , and thus:

$$g^{30}=\left(g^{15}\right)^2\implies ord(g^{30})=ord(g^2)=68$$

and you can save a lot of annoying calculations.

Now, since it is given $\;G\;$ is *cyclic*, then it has **one unique subgroup of each order dividing** $\;136\;$ (and, BTW, all of them cyclic as well...), so all you have to do now is to calculate how many divisors $\;136\;$ has...

Comment: thank you! so i calculated and found out that 136 has 8 divisors...does that mean there are 8 subgroups containing this subgroup?

Comment: @Ashley No. There are $\;8\;$ subgroups **in the whole group** $\;G\;$ ...! Now, if you know already all the above, how many subgroups, **and which ones exactly**, does a group of order $\;136\;$ have that contain **the** subgroup of order $\;68\;$ ...??

Comment: 1, 2, 4, 17, 34, 68 are the divisors of 68. 1, 2, 4, 8, 17, 34, 68, 136 are the divisors of 136. so there are 7? 1,2,4,17,34,68

Comment: @Ashley But you wrote "...that **contain** this subgroup", not "...that **are contained** in this subgroup" ...! No set with less than $\;n\;$ elements can contain a set with $\;n\;$ elements.

Comment: i'm so sorry i'm slow to getting this... but okay that last sentence makes sense. so 136 and 68 are the only ones that would work since they are larger than (or equal to 68)...the others are too small to contain that many elements

Comment: @Ashley Exactly. And don't worry: abstract stuff can be tough at start for most of us. Observe that **only** cyclic groups have *one unique subgroup* of any order that divides the group's, and that any of these subgroups is contained in any other subgroup of order a multiple of the subgroup's....this doesn't happen in other cases. Not even close...